# How to use the .NET XMLSerializer Deserialize in DesignTime

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, design-time

I have some config files in my project which can be changed at runtime using a usercontrol with a listbox and a propertygrid. With this approach i have to copy the config files from the \bin\debug\ folders everytime they are changed by hand into the project folder.

Now i want to change the content of these files at design time. So i began to write my own Designer. The first time the designer is opened everything works fine, but when the project gets rebuild it doesnt work anymore. An InvalidCastException occurs when the deserialized object gets casted and it seems to be a problem described at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/csharpgeneral/thread/7192f23e-7d43-47b5-b401-5fcd19671cf6 The types are equal but they arent in the same assembly.

This is a sample where the same problem occurs when adding the UserControl1 to a Form:

```
public class SerializerTest
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

[Designer(typeof(MyDesigner))]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String Content 
    {
        get { return this.textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}

class MyDesigner : ControlDesigner
{ 
    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);
        try
        {
            string fName = @"D:\XMLSerializerTest\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\test.xml";
            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializerTest));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Open);
            SerializerTest test = (SerializerTest)xmlSer.Deserialize(fs);
            ((UserControl1)this.Control).Content = (test != null) ? test.ToString() + " \n" + test.Name : "NULL";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ((UserControl1)this.Control).Content = ex.Message; }
    }
}
```

It seems that the serializer is still cached and used after a rebuild. So i already tried a more complex constructor, where no caching should be used, but the behaviour doesnt changed.

Does anyone know how to avoid the invalidcastexception?

Comment: I'm curious.  what do you hope to gain from doing this?  you have a bunch of data at "design time"; you compile and deploy.  where does that data go?  It's gets lost if it's in some xml file somewhere.  At which point; what are you doing at design time?

Answer (score 0):

Try pre-generating the XML serialization assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=VS.100%29.aspx